# How to run a Tensorflow-Lite inference in (Android Studio) NDK (C / C++ API)?

Tags: c++, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk, tensorflow-lite

## Info

- I built a Tensorflow (TF) model from Keras and converted it to Tensorflow-Lite (TFL)
- I built an Android app in Android Studio and used the Java API to run the TFL model
- In the Java app, I used the TFL Support Library (see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/experimental/support/java/README.md)), and the TensorFlow Lite AAR from JCenter by including `implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+'` under my `build.gradle` dependencies

Inference times are not so great, so now I want to use TFL in Android's NDK.

So I built an exact copy of the Java app in Android Studio's NDK, and now I'm trying to include the TFL libs in the project. I followed [TensorFlow-Lite's Android guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/android#build_tensorflow_lite_locally) and built the TFL library locally (and got an AAR file), and included the library in my NDK project in Android Studio.

Now I'm trying to use the TFL library in my C++ file, by trying to `#include` it in code, but I get an error message: `cannot find tensorflow` (or any other name I'm trying to use, according to the name I give it in my `CMakeLists.txt` file).

## Files

App *build.gradle*:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ndk.tflite"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }

        ndk {
            abiFilters 'arm64-v8a'
        }

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    // tf lite
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress "tflite"
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
            version "3.10.2"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    // tflite build
    compile(name:'tensorflow-lite', ext:'aar')

}
```

Project *build.gradle*:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

        // native tflite
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }

    }

}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

*CMakeLists.txt*:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             native-lib.cpp )

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
        tensorflow-lite

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        native-lib.cpp )

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )


target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib tensorflow-lite

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib} )
```

*native-lib.cpp*:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>

#include "tensorflow"

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_xvu_f32c_1jni_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject /* this */) {
    std::string hello = "Hello from C++";
    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}

class FlatBufferModel {
    // Build a model based on a file. Return a nullptr in case of failure.
    static std::unique_ptr<FlatBufferModel> BuildFromFile(
            const char* filename,
            ErrorReporter* error_reporter);

    // Build a model based on a pre-loaded flatbuffer. The caller retains
    // ownership of the buffer and should keep it alive until the returned object
    // is destroyed. Return a nullptr in case of failure.
    static std::unique_ptr<FlatBufferModel> BuildFromBuffer(
            const char* buffer,
            size_t buffer_size,
            ErrorReporter* error_reporter);
};
```

## Progress

I also tried to follow these:

- [Problems with using tensorflow lite C++ API in Android Studio Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49834875/problems-with-using-tensorflow-lite-c-api-in-android-studio-project/50332808#50332808)
- [Android C++ NDK : some shared libraries refuses to link in runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60925493/android-c-ndk-some-shared-libraries-refuses-to-link-in-runtime)
- [How to build TensorFlow Lite as a static library and link to it from a separate (CMake) project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55125977/how-to-build-tensorflow-lite-as-a-static-library-and-link-to-it-from-a-separate)
- [how to set input of Tensorflow Lite C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50150701/how-to-set-input-of-tensorflow-lite-c)
- [How can I build only TensorFlow lite and not all TensorFlow from source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57151987/how-can-i-build-only-tensorflow-lite-and-not-all-tensorflow-from-source)

but in my case I used Bazel to build the TFL libs.

Trying to build the classification demo of ([label_image](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite/examples/label_image)), I managed to build it and `adb push` to my device, but when trying to run I got the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not open './mobilenet_quant_v1_224.tflite'.
Failed to mmap model ./mobilenet_quant_v1_224.tflite
```

- I followed [zimenglyu's post](https://github.com/zimenglyu/zimenglyu/blob/master/_posts/2018-11-27-tflite-android-ndk-eng.markdown): trying to set `android_sdk_repository` / `android_ndk_repository` in `WORKSPACE` got me an error: `WORKSPACE:149:1: Cannot redefine repository after any load statement in the WORKSPACE file (for repository 'androidsdk')`, and locating these statements at different places resulted in the same error.
- I deleted these changes to `WORKSPACE` and continued with zimenglyu's post: I've compiled `libtensorflowLite.so`, and edited `CMakeLists.txt` so that the `libtensorflowLite.so` file was referenced, but left the `FlatBuffer` part out. The Android project compiled successfully, but there was no evident change, I still can't include any TFLite libraries.

Trying to compile TFL, I added a `cc_binary` to `tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/BUILD` (following the [label_image example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite/examples/label_image)):

```
cc_binary(
    name = "native-lib",
    srcs = [
        "native-lib.cpp",
    ],
    linkopts = tflite_experimental_runtime_linkopts() + select({
        "//tensorflow:android": [
            "-pie",
            "-lm",
        ],
        "//conditions:default": [],
    }),
    deps = [
        "//tensorflow/lite/c:common",
        "//tensorflow/lite:framework",
        "//tensorflow/lite:string_util",
        "//tensorflow/lite/delegates/nnapi:nnapi_delegate",
        "//tensorflow/lite/kernels:builtin_ops",
        "//tensorflow/lite/profiling:profiler",
        "//tensorflow/lite/tools/evaluation:utils",
    ] + select({
        "//tensorflow:android": [
            "//tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu:delegate",
        ],
        "//tensorflow:android_arm64": [
            "//tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu:delegate",
        ],
        "//conditions:default": [],
    }),
)
```

and trying to build it for `x86_64`, and `arm64-v8a` I get an error: `cc_toolchain_suite rule @local_config_cc//:toolchain: cc_toolchain_suite '@local_config_cc//:toolchain' does not contain a toolchain for cpu 'x86_64'`.

Checking `external/local_config_cc/BUILD` (which provided the error) in line 47:

```
cc_toolchain_suite(
    name = "toolchain",
    toolchains = {
        "k8|compiler": ":cc-compiler-k8",
        "k8": ":cc-compiler-k8",
        "armeabi-v7a|compiler": ":cc-compiler-armeabi-v7a",
        "armeabi-v7a": ":cc-compiler-armeabi-v7a",
    },
)
```

and these are the only 2 `cc_toolchain`s found. Searching the repository for "cc-compiler-" I only found "**aarch64**", which I assumed is for the 64-bit ARM, but nothing with "x86_64". There are "x64_windows", though - and I'm on Linux.

Trying to build with aarch64 like so:

```
bazel build -c opt --fat_apk_cpu=aarch64 --cpu=aarch64 --host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain //tensorflow/lite/java:tensorflow-lite
```

results in an error:

```
ERROR: /.../external/local_config_cc/BUILD:47:1: in cc_toolchain_suite rule @local_config_cc//:toolchain: cc_toolchain_suite '@local_config_cc//:toolchain' does not contain a toolchain for cpu 'aarch64'
```

#### Using the libraries in Android Studio:

I was able to build the library for `x86_64` architecture by changing the `soname` in build config and using full paths in `CMakeLists.txt`. This resulted in a `.so` shared library. Also - I was able to build the library for `arm64-v8a` using the TFLite Docker container, by adjusting the `aarch64_makefile.inc` file, but I did not change any build options, and let `build_aarch64_lib.sh` whatever it builds. This resulted in a `.a` static library.

So now I have two TFLite libs, but I'm still unable to use them (I can't `#include "..."` anything for example).

When trying to build the project, using only `x86_64` works fine, but trying to include the `arm64-v8a` library results in ninja error: `'.../libtensorflow-lite.a', needed by '.../app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libnative-lib.so', missing and no known rule to make it`.

#### Different approach - build/compile source files with Gradle:

1. I created a Native C++ project in Android Studio
2. I took the basic C/C++ source files and headers from Tensorflow's `lite` directory, and created a similar structure in `app/src/main/cpp`, in which I include the (A) tensorflow, (B) absl and (C) flatbuffers files
3. I changed the `#include "tensorflow/...` lines in all of tensorflow's header files to relative paths so the compiler can find them.
4. In the app's `build.gradle` I added a no-compression line for the `.tflite` file: `aaptOptions { noCompress "tflite" }`
5. I added an `assets` directory to the app
6. In `native-lib.cpp` I added [some example code from the TFLite website](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference#load_and_run_a_model_in_c)
7. Tried to build the project with the source files included (build target is `arm64-v8a`).

I get an error:

```
/path/to/Android/Sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:2339: error: undefined reference to 'tflite::impl::Interpreter::~Interpreter()'
```

in `<memory>`, line 2339 is the `"delete __ptr;"` line:

```
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY void operator()(_Tp* __ptr) const _NOEXCEPT {
    static_assert(sizeof(_Tp) > 0,
                  "default_delete can not delete incomplete type");
    static_assert(!is_void<_Tp>::value,
                  "default_delete can not delete incomplete type");
    delete __ptr;
  }
```

## Question

How can I include the TFLite libraries in Android Studio, so I can run a TFL inference from the NDK?

Alternatively - how can I use gradle (currently with **cmake**) to build and compile the source files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use Native TFL with C-API in the following way:

#### SETUP:

1. Download the latest version of [TensorFlow Lite AAR file](https://bintray.com/google/tensorflow/tensorflow-lite)
2. Change the file type of downloaded `.arr` file to `.zip` and unzip the file to get the shared library (`.so` file)
3. Download all header files from the `c` directory in the [TFL repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite/c)
4. Create an Android C++ app in Android Studio
5. Create a `jni` directory (`New` -> `Folder` -> `JNI Folder`) in `app/src/main` and also create architecture sub-directories in it (`arm64-v8a` or `x86_64` for example)
6. Put all header files in the `jni` directory (next to the architecture directories), and put the shared library inside the architecture directory/ies
7. Open the `CMakeLists.txt` file and include an `add_library` stanza for the TFL library, the path to the shared library in a `set_target_properties` stanza and the headers in `include_directories` stanza (see below, in NOTES section)
8. Sync Gradle

#### USAGE:

In `native-lib.cpp` include the headers, for example:

```
#include "../jni/c_api.h"
#include "../jni/common.h"
#include "../jni/builtin_ops.h"
```

TFL functions can be called directly, for example:

```
TfLiteModel * model = TfLiteModelCreateFromFile(full_path);
TfLiteInterpreter * interpreter = TfLiteInterpreterCreate(model);
TfLiteInterpreterAllocateTensors(interpreter);
TfLiteTensor * input_tensor =
            TfLiteInterpreterGetInputTensor(interpreter, 0);
const TfLiteTensor * output_tensor =
            TfLiteInterpreterGetOutputTensor(interpreter, 0);
TfLiteStatus from_status = TfLiteTensorCopyFromBuffer(
            input_tensor,
            input_data,
            TfLiteTensorByteSize(input_tensor));
TfLiteStatus interpreter_invoke_status = TfLiteInterpreterInvoke(interpreter);
TfLiteStatus to_status = TfLiteTensorCopyToBuffer(
            output_tensor,
            output_data,
            TfLiteTensorByteSize(output_tensor));
```

#### NOTES:

- In this setup SDK version 29 was used
- `cmake` environment also included `cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"`

`CMakeLists.txt` example:

```
set(JNI_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../jni)
add_library(tflite-lib SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(tflite-lib
        PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${JNI_DIR}/${ANDROID_ABI}/libtfl.so)
include_directories( ${JNI_DIR} )
target_link_libraries(
        native-lib
        tflite-lib
        ...)
```

Comment: If the model is in the assets folder how do you pass the full path to the JNI?  because the TfLiteModelCreateFromFile is expecting a *char so how is the code there?

Comment: I managed to load the model from buffer with this code  void* modelBuffer = (*env).GetDirectBufferAddress(byteBuffer);
TfLiteModel* model = TfLiteModelCreate(modelBuffer, modelSize);  So I am using TfLiteModelCreate instead of  TfLiteModelCreateFromFile because tflite files are stored in the assets folder and that folder can not provide a path, I am just curious how do you manage to load the tflite model from a file path?

Comment: Copy the model from the assets folder (once for all) to the data/data/[app]/. This way the "TfLiteModelCreateFromFile" can work from the C API. It works for me.

Comment: Hey AlejandroUribeSánchez, sorry it took me a while to answer... as @Sqripter suggested, Android's Internal Storage would probably be the best way to go (see https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage and https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific for more info)... You can use Android Studio's File Explorer (https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer) to copy the files into the Internal Storage.

Comment: man you saved my life

Answer (score 2):

I have also struggled with building TF Lite C++ APIs for Android. Fortunately, I managed to make it work.

The problem is we need to configure the Bazel build process before running the `bazel build ...` commands. The TF Lite Android Quick Start guide doesn't mention it.

**Step-by-step guide** (https://github.com/cuongvng/TF-Lite-Cpp-API-for-Android):

- Step 1: [Install Bazel](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/4.0.0/install.html)
- Step 2: Clone the [TensorFlow repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow)

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow
cd ./tensorflow/
```

- **Step 3: Configure Android build**
  Before running the `bazel build ...` command, you need to configure the build process. Do so by executing

```
./configure
```

The `configure` file is at the root of the tensorflow directory, which you `cd` to at Step 2.
Now you have to input some configurations on the command line:

```
$ ./configure
You have bazel 3.7.2-homebrew installed.
Please specify the location of python. [Default is /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3]: /Users/cuongvng/opt/miniconda3/envs/style-transfer-tf-lite/bin/python
```

First is the location of python, because `./configure` executes the `.configure.py` file.
Choose the location that has Numpy installed, otherwise the later build will fail.
Here I point it to the python executable of a conda environment.

Next,

```
Found possible Python library paths:
  /Users/cuongvng/opt/miniconda3/envs/style-transfer-tf-lite/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Please input the desired Python library path to use.  Default is [/Users/cuongvng/opt/miniconda3/envs/style-transfer-tf-lite/lib/python3.7/site-packages]
```

I press `Enter` to use the default site-packages, which contains necessary libraries to build TF.

Next,

```
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with ROCm support? [y/N]: N
No ROCm support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with CUDA support? [y/N]: N
No CUDA support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to download a fresh release of clang? (Experimental) [y/N]: N
Clang will not be downloaded.

Please specify optimization flags to use during compilation when bazel option "--config=opt" is specified [Default is -Wno-sign-compare]:
```

Key in as showed above, on the last line type `Enter`.
Then it asks you whether to configure ./WORKSPACE for Android builds, type **y** to add configurations.

```
Would you like to interactively configure ./WORKSPACE for Android builds? [y/N]: y
Searching for NDK and SDK installations.

Please specify the home path of the Android NDK to use. [Default is /Users/cuongvng/library/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle]: /Users/cuongvng/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462
```

That is the home path of the Android NDK (version 21.1.6352462) on my local machine.
Note that when you `ls` the path, it must include `platforms`, e.g.:

```
$ ls /Users/cuongvng/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462
CHANGELOG.md      build             ndk-stack         prebuilt          source.properties wrap.sh
NOTICE            meta              ndk-which         python-packages   sources
NOTICE.toolchain  ndk-build         package.xml       shader-tools      sysroot
README.md         ndk-gdb           platforms         simpleperf        toolchains
```

For now I ignore the resulting WARNING, then choose the min NDK API level

```
WARNING: The NDK version in /Users/cuongvng/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462 is 21, which is not supported by Bazel (officially supported versions: [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]). Please use another version. Compiling Android targets may result in confusing errors.

Please specify the (min) Android NDK API level to use. [Available levels: ['16', '17', '18', '19', '21', '22', '23', '24', '26', '27', '28', '29']] [Default is 21]: 29
```

Next

```
Please specify the home path of the Android SDK to use. [Default is /Users/cuongvng/library/Android/Sdk]: /Users/cuongvng/Library/Android/sdk

Please specify the Android SDK API level to use. [Available levels: ['28', '29', '30']] [Default is 30]: 30

Please specify an Android build tools version to use. [Available versions: ['29.0.2', '29.0.3', '30.0.3', '31.0.0-rc1']] [Default is 31.0.0-rc1]: 30.0.3
```

That is all for Android build configs. Choose `N` for all questions appearing later:

- Step 4: Build the shared library (`.so`)
  Now you can run the bazel build command to generate libraries for your target architecture:

```
bazel build -c opt --config=android_arm //tensorflow/lite:libtensorflowlite.so
# or
bazel build -c opt --config=android_arm64 //tensorflow/lite:libtensorflowlite.so
```

It should work without errors.
The generated library would be saved at `./bazel-bin/tensorflow/lite/libtensorflowlite.so`.

Comment: Worked for me with small changes due to my code